# Generate images at given time from flv video using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I am using the following command in ffmpeg to generate thumbnails. It is working perfect.

```
ffmpeg -i videofile.flv -an -ss 01:00:00 -an -r 1 -vframes 1 -y ".$outputdir."/".$groupid."_".$i.".jpg
```

But problem is I have different seek times of a video from where thumbnails have to be generated and right now Iam using a loop which is running very slow. I found the reason as ffmpeg seeks to the given time for every command. I tried forking the process but is not effective. Is there anyways i can optimise the command so the repetitive seeks can be avoided?

Comment: Your question is unclear to me. Are you trying to get multiple output images (with varied `-ss` values) from one input? Note that ffmpeg usage questions are more suitable for superuser.com and this question can be migrated there.

Comment: yes...exactly for different ss values

Comment: Are the `-ss` values the same for all inputs, and are the values consistently spaced (such as every 60 seconds)?

Comment: no -ss values are different..they are not spaced consistently..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lot of research, found that its not possible. FFMPEG should consider adding option for this...it saves lot of execution time...

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
ffmpeg -ss 01:00:00 -i videofile.flv ....
```

Using `-ss` as an input option is often faster but can be less accurate. FFmpeg will immediately seek first and then begin decoding at your desired `-ss` value; however it is potentially not frame accurate as using `-ss` as an output option which additionally decodes everything before your `-ss` value.

Comment: but i know this one...i have got set of -ss values which i want to use in a single command..

Comment: @LordNeckbeard I didn't know it was potentially less accurate, I guess in my attempts I got lucky...

Comment: @CodeJack In the command line you originally posted the -ss option does not come IMEDIATELLY AFTER ffmpeg.exe, it comes after -i. You have to put -ss as the first thing in that command, it will be faster. But as you can see, it could fail to decode the exact frame you want to take a snapshot of, it could be a little off or even result in a "bad screenshot".

Answer (score 0):

it makes a lot of difference if you first define -i and later -ss or the other way around. For more information look at the answer from this post:

[another question at stack overflow.com: ffmpeg weird behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6984628/ffmpeg-ss-weird-behaviour)

hth